# Showing custom cooldown messages for a command usind discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to add a cooldown for my discord.py bot such that the user is not able to spam a command, it works fine in my case. I use the following decorator and `bot.event` and I'm able to get the bot to send a message saying that cooldown is in place.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send(f"wait for {round(error.retry_after, 2)} seconds before trying again")
```

I do this by using this decoration in my command.

```py
@bot.command(name="dice", help="bet a certain amount of money in dice")
@commands.cooldown(1, 1200, commands.BucketType.user)
```

However the problem is that I have a couple different commands with cooldown and I'd like to send a custom message for each one of these different commands, such as maybe for the `dice` command the bot could say "Gambling a bit too much is bad, don't you think?" and for a `mine` command the bot could say "Coins do not rain straight from the sky!" and so on and so forth.

I would like to know if there was some way to essentially detect what command the bot is receiving and provide a different cooldown message  based on that.

TL;DR How do I make personalized cooldown messages for each command?

Comment: `for command in bot.commands():`, what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I was trying to see if i could get the name of the command and if command == "mine" for example then the cooldown message would be "Coins do not rain straight from the sky!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is checking what command was invoked, we can do that with the provided context:

```py
if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
    if ctx.command.name == 'mine':
         await ctx.send("Coins dont rain from the sky")
    elif ctx.command.name == 'beg':
         await ctx.send("there is no one in the street to beg to")
    else:
         await ctx.send('command is on cooldown')
```

### References:

- [`ctx.command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context.command)
- [`command.name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Command.name)

Note: `command.name` is the name of the function by default, you can change it by passing `name=bar` in the `bot.command` decorator.